# Norm of the gradient of a vector field in Cartesian versus Cylindrical coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, differential-forms

It is well known that for a vector $\textbf{v}=R\textbf{e}_r+\Theta\textbf{e}_{\theta}+Z\textbf{e}_z$, its 2-norm is $\|\textbf{v}\|_2=\sqrt{R^2+Z^2}$ instead of $\sqrt{R^2+\Theta^2+Z^2}$.

Now, for a 2-tensor, let's take the gradient of a vector field $\textbf{u}=(u_1,u_2,u_3)=(u_r,u_{\theta},u_z)$ as an example:

Under Cartesian coordinates, $\nabla \textbf{u}$ is $$\nabla \textbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_{x}u_1 && \partial_{y}u_1 && \partial_{z}u_1 \\
\partial_{x}u_2 && \partial_{y}u_2 && \partial_{z}u_2 \\
\partial_{x}u_3 && \partial_{y}u_3 && \partial_{z}u_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
whose 2-norm (entry-wise Frobenius norm) is simply the square-root of the sum of squares of its entries.

However, under cylindrical coordinates, we have 
 $$\nabla \textbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_{r}u_r && \frac{1}{r}(\partial_{\theta}u_r-u_{\theta}) && \partial_{z}u_r \\
\partial_{r}u_{\theta} && \frac{1}{r}(\partial_{\theta}u_{\theta}+u_{r}) && \partial_{z}u_{\theta} \\
\partial_{r}u_z && \frac{1}{r}\partial_{\theta}u_z && \partial_{z}u_z
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
My question is, is the 2-norm (the norm equivalent to the 2-norm under Cartesian coordinates) of it still the square-root of the sum of squares of its entries in the case of cylindrical coordinates? I feel that this is not the case just like the analoge of the 2-norm of a 1D tensor $\textbf{v}$ shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be careful about the distinction between points and vectors. While a point is described by cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$ and has distance $\sqrt{r^2 + z^2}$ from the origin, a vector $v$ based at a point is described by *Cartesian coordinates locally aligned to the cylindrical coordinates* - i.e. $v = v^r e_r + v^\theta e_\theta + v^z e_z$, where the basis $e_r,e_\theta,e_z$ depends on the base point - it's the orthonormal basis at the point aligned to the corresponding coordinate lines.

Here's a decent picture from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_coordinates):

[image]

Thus the squared norm of such a vector is indeed defined by the sum of squares of its components.

Comment: Thanks. But we have $|v|=\sqrt{v_r^2+v_z^2}$ instead of $\sqrt{v_r^2+v_{\theta}^2+v_z^2}$, which differs by a squared $\theta$ component. So it is it not always sum of squares of all the components in the case of cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: @user31899: that's simply not true. Do you understand the distinction I'm trying to highlight in this answer? You're treating $v$ like a point, not a vector. The distinction is essential when working with non-linear coordinates.

Comment: Yeah I see the distinction now. But how to express $|\nabla \textbf{u}|$ in terms of $r,\theta,z$ given $\textbf{u}$ being a vector field ? Is it still the sqaure-root of the sum of all the $9$ entries in the matrix representation of $|\nabla \textbf{u}|$ under cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: @user31899: yes, that's right. You should be able to verify this by making substitutions using the multivariable chain rule.